# Snake4d - a 4 spatial dimensional game

Tags: c++, opengl, 4d

I wrote a little 4 spatial dimension game, it's a 4D snake. The rule are the same as the game for the old Nokia cell phone - eat the food, don't cross yourself, don't go out of the borders.

What do you think of the idea? How do I make a better graphic of the UI? Do you have any suggestion? Like this actually seem a DOS game ...

Here is a little explanatory video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8IUnqm8j4BE

And here there is a new version I did with OpenGL and C++: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NaeqUp3jbls

Moreover I have a question, which from the two representation above you like more? Or better, do you have any idea how to represent the 4 dimension at the best?

Btw any comments, suggestions, and questions are appreciated about the UI, the game concept, etc.

Comment: I guess 4D is way over my mind's capacities!

Comment: Is that really 4D though (at least when thinking about 4D as time)? It seems like the fourth dimension is just using a hypercube to alter the shape of the three existing dimensions (i.e. changing squares into different polyhedra or "squishing" them). I'd imagine it to break up the snake and leave parts behind as you go forward and backwards in time, but then again hypercubes have always confused me. :)

Comment: this is really 4d, the game engine use 4d vectors (x,y,z,w) to calculate the position of the snake. I did this game to try to understand the 4th dimensional projection. And I hoped to see something like you said, snake frammenting or warping around. But it's not like that, actually is the same from 2d to 3d, the snake is always a continuous line, but you see it distorted... or squished.

Comment: - votes are because of the game, the style, the fact you don't belive it's actually 4d?

Comment: @Pella86: You're asking too many questions at once. "How to make UI Graphics?" is entirely different from "How to represent the 4th dimension?". There are already some UI questions around, so I suggest you change this question to be about how to represent the 4th dimension..

Comment: I don't wanted to open more than one topic about this... ;) it was just to have a topic where to discuss the graphic of the game, I know stackexchange is for specific question. But anyway I don't wanted to spam this for with one topic for every problem I have. And btw... I'm not asking how to do UI, I'm asking a style opinion... I tried to ask this on "gaming" but they kindly invited me to come here ;)

Comment: will the snake actually bite me if I lose?

Comment: ahah ;) can be... if you activate the boolean snake_bite_user = TRUE;

Comment: The hypercube you have there isn't actually 4d. It's only a projection of a 4d cube in 3d (even though it's actually on a 2d surface). I don't think 4d is a viable game mechanic.

Comment: I know it's only a 3d projection, as human we cannot see the 4th dimension. But... the 4d maze of urticator.net was used to test if humans could orient themself in a projected 4-space, and yes, actually with a little bit of exercise one can do it. Anyway, I never said you will be able to see in 4 dimension, that's not possible.

Comment: We don't consider asking multiple questions spam, in general we like to keep one question, per question.

Comment: stackoverflow has an other opinion, but ok I'll update my questions :D

Comment: Generally speaking, questions should be practical questions to answers you face and not chatty "What do you think?" type questions.  http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some thoughts:

Your first video refers to Time when introducing your fourth dimension.  *Time is not a spatial dimension* and, therefore, is a metaphor that will only serve to confuse your audience.

From a quick Google search, I wasn't able to find any useful information about how to render 4 spatial dimensions onto a 2D screen but there must be some out there. The math behind 3D -> 2D is a right about at the limits of my mathematics mastery so I can't begin to postulate any effective ways to render an additional dimension. But, there's likely someone working on such research right now somewhere; you'll just need to find it.

The complexity of understanding movement between 4 dimensions is likely going to be beyond the grasp of much of your audience unless you spend a lot of time adjusting and catering to players through prototyping and playtesting.  The difficulty of this dimensional leap is somewhat facetiously (but still applicably) addressed in [this XKCD comic](http://xkcd.com/721/).

I'm not sure if you've heard of a game called [Miegakure](http://marctenbosch.com/miegakure/).  It's a 4D platformer in which the player can shift between which 3 of the 4 spatial dimensions are visible/accessible.  Unfortunately, the game is not yet released but there are some demo videos available on the game's site.  Perhaps its approach to 4 dimensions could be helpful to you.

Good luck!

Comment: +1. Since everything is projected to 2D, we actually lose 2 dimensions which is probably too much to handle. 4D might be interesting for visualizations, but for a game, well, I doubt it would work. The game might work better if it were stereoscopic (real 3D), in that case we would only lose 1 dimension 4D -> 3D.

Comment: @bummzack: Stereoscopic version: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yTQIFVmx-1M

Comment: @chaosTechnician: thx for the answer! about the spatial dimension / time issue. Yes I know it, I will make a new video for the new version, where I avoid this metaphor. I found http://eusebeia.dyndns.org/4d/index.html this website, the only thing I don't do for now is an HSR of the 4d space. I heard about Miegakure, I don't like their representation because is not using the 4d perspective.